# Explicação do código

Tags: c

Olá, poderia explicar a parte desse código?

```
int nota[2];
    scanf( "%s %d", nome, &horas );
```

E essa parte

```
int i = 0;

    while( i < 2 ) {
        scanf( "%d", &nota[i] );
        if( nota[i] > 100 || nota[i] < 0 ) {
            // printf( "Nota fora do intervalo\n" );
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }

    //Media Ponderada
    float calculo = media * 0.4 + nota[0] * 0.1 + nota[1] * 0.5;

    if( nota[1] < 70 ) {
```

**While (i < 2), **nota[i]**, **nota[0]**, **nota[1]** e **nota[2]**

Comment: Poste o código completo. No que você postou faltam definições de variáveis e também cálculos (por exemplo o cálculo ou leitura de media). A última linha não faz sentido.

Comment: @anonimo poderei postar em um site para acesso à parte.

Answer (score 0):

```
int nota[2]; <- cria uma variável na forma de array com 2 posicoes
    scanf( "%s %d", nome, &horas );// <- recebe a informação digitada no cmd



int i = 0;

    while( i < 2 ) {// <- estrutura de repetição que ira fazer até que o 'i' seja menor que 2
        scanf( "%d", &nota[i] );
        if( nota[i] > 100 || nota[i] < 0 ) { //<- ira verificar se a nota de posição 'i' é maior que 100  ou menor que 0
            // printf( "Nota fora do intervalo\n" );
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }

    //Media Ponderada
    float calculo = media * 0.4 + nota[0] * 0.1 + nota[1] * 0.5;

    if( nota[1] < 70 ) {
```

Comment: E a **nota[0]** ?

Comment: é referente ao primeiro valor do nota. Em computação começa a contar a partir do 0

Comment: Dba, poderia encontrar em contato comigo?

Comment: Irei atualizar meu perfil com o facebook ai você entra lá.

Comment: Ficarei no aguardo. Att.